# Monero GUI - See the mining in progress

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, mining

I am not interested in joining a pool nor buying fancy hardware. I just want to mine on my macbook in the background, and play my luck.

I've installed the official Monero GUI app, and it's mining using 1 CPU thread.

At the bottom of the screen, there is a little status text that most of the time simply says "Mining at 0 H/s", and sometimes jumps to 50 H/s for like 3 seconds.

First, is it normal that it only intermittently shows a positive hashrate?

Second, is there a better way to "see" the mining in action? I don't know maybe something more verbose that shows every time it attempts to solve a block, with some stats about what happened?

The daemon log only prints once in a while, and what it prints does not say much:

```
Height: 1502864/1502864 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 0 H/s, net hash
760.04 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 6h 8m 31s
```

I don't mind using some command-line tool instead of the GUI (as long as it works on macOS and lets me throttle it to only 1 CPU thread).

Comment: On average it would take you 28253.61 Days to mine a block. might want to consider rethinking not joining a pool if you want fractions of Monero to play with. Or consider switching to the testnet for more of a chance of getting some Monero the current testnet hash rate is 234 H/s according to: https://testnet.xmrchain.com/

Comment: Right like I said I see it more like a lottery, not an investment. People buy lottery tickets for an entire lifetime without ever winning, yet they still buy them :) I don't mind having very low chances, just that the ONE ticket I buy actually gets entered in the system to have my 1 chance.

Comment: I believe there was a bug with hash rate reporting, not sure whether it got fixed. Which version are you running ? And are you triyng to use "smart mining" mode, where mining is done when the CPU is otherwise idle ?

Comment: GUI v0.11.1.0, Monero v0.11.1.0-2-gc328163. I don't use the background mode.

Comment: Please use the newest wallet version. The current one is 0.12.2